# handleSubmit() an onSubmit function or pass onSubmit as a prop redux-form On ReactJS

Tags: redux, prop

Uncaught Error: You must either pass handleSubmit() an onSubmit function or pass onSubmit as a prop

my code here,

Comment: Please post relevant code here

Comment: my code here, http://freetexthost.com/e1t106562p  I have simple form with validate on submit button not working.